# Converting pitches into a monophonic midi

Tags: python, audio, numpy, midi

Here's the question :- 
I used a software called aubio to extract pitches from an mp3 file and stored them in a  dictionary. I am using python. 
My dictionary looks like this :-

```
dict pitches = {time : principal frequency, ... }
```

I've used the formula formula to convert the principal frquencies into midi numbers.

```
d = 69 + 12*log_2 (f / 440)
```

I am looking to perform some mathematical operations on the pitches and then listen to the result.

Is there a way I can convert this data into monophonic midi file?

Answer (score 0):

The [Python MIDI Library](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) looks to have a useful interface for creating a MIDI file, and the README offers a very clear example of how to go about it.

Comment: I looked into it. I looked into the contents of Pattern object. I has of Note On and Note Off events. It has ticks, velocity and pitch parameters associated with each of these events. 
I only have pitches and associated timestamps to work with.

Comment: This is where you have to improvise. You can set a fixed velocity for each note. You could try setting the Note Off times about 90% of the way to the next Note On. Then the tick values are the deltas between the successive MIDI events.